# jQuery $.when() function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a small piece of code, which translate a Lat-Long location to a human-readable address. I would like the translation to happen first before the human-readable address is shown. That's why I want to use $.when() to finish the translation first.

However, when running, the human-readable address is not shown, only the default value of 'xxx' is shown. There is also no error detected.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

var lat1 = 39.983313,
  lon1 = -0.031963;

var addressLatLng = {
  lat: parseFloat(lat1),
  lng: parseFloat(lon1)
};

var addressHumanReadable = 'xxx';

$.when(
  geocoder.geocode({
    'location': addressLatLng
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      if (results[0]) {
        addressHumanReadable = results[0].formatted_address;

      } else {
        window.alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  })
).done(function(x) {
  alert(addressHumanReadable);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't feed the `$.when` with a `Deferred` or a `Promise` or a `Thenable`, so it fires `done` right away (more info here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

So here is your code... changed a little, so that it can perform your dark magic.

```
// With the power of Google Maps...
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

// .. and some magic numbers!
var lat1 = 39.983313;
var lon1 = -0.031963;

// We shall translate them...
var addressLatLng = {
  lat: parseFloat(lat1),
  lng: parseFloat(lon1)
};

// ... to something that a Human can process!
var addressHumanReadable = 'xxx';

$.when(
    // We execute an anomymous function
    // that help us keep things clean
    (function(){
        // We need a deferred to indicate when we are ready
        var isDone = $.Deferred();

        // Run your async function
        geocoder.geocode(
            {'location': addressLatLng},
            function(results, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    if (results[0]) {
                        addressHumanReadable = results[0].formatted_address;
                    }
                    else {
                        window.alert('No results found');
                    }
                }
                else {
                    window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                }

                // Set deferred as resolved
                isDone.resolve();
            }
        );

        // Return a jquery deferred
        return isDone;
    })()
).done(function() {
    // MAGIC!
    alert(addressHumanReadable);
});
```

---

But wait there's more! I don't like global variables... I also don't like when alerts interrupt my code flow... so ... we can remove `addressHumanReadable` and the alerts inside geocode.

```
// With the power of Google Maps...
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

// .. and some magic numbers!
var lat1 = 39.983313;
var lon1 = -23452.031963;

// We shall translate them...
var addressLatLng = {
    lat: parseFloat(lat1),
    lng: parseFloat(lon1)
};

$.when(
    // We execute an anomymous function
    // that help us keep things clean
    (function(){
        // We need a deferred to indicate when we are ready
        var isDone = $.Deferred();

        // Run your async function
        geocoder.geocode(
            {'location': addressLatLng},
            function(results, status) {
                // Check for errors
                if (status !== 'OK') {
                    console.log('Oups... error : ' + status);
                    isDone.resolve(false);
                    return;
                }

                // Check if failed to resolve
                if (!results[0]) {
                    isDone.resolve(false);
                    return;
                }

                // No errors... so...
                isDone.resolve(results[0].formatted_address);
            }
        );

        // Return a jquery deferred
        return isDone;
    })()
).done(function(result) {
    if (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
    else {
        alert('Address not found!');
    }
});
```

Happy javascript coding!